# Edit embedded excel data silently, in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to edit embedded excel data silently in PowerPoint 2010. Unfortunately when you use:

```
gChartData.Activate
```

It opens the Excel document over the presentation. Is there a way to activate the ChartData without opening Excel?

Full Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myChart As Chart
Dim gChartData As ChartData
Dim gWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim gWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart
Set gChartData = myChart.ChartData

gChartData.Activate

Set gWorkBook = gChartData.Workbook

Set gWorkSheet = gWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

gWorkSheet.Range("B2").Value = 1

Set gWorkSheet = Nothing
Set gWorkBook = Nothing
Set gChartData = Nothing
Set myChart = Nothing


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the gChartData.Activate?

Answer (score 3):

Steven,

While the `Activate` line is necessary to get access to the underlying Workbook adding a simple `gWorkBook.Close` to your code (before setting it to Nothing) will close Excel again rather than leave it on top as your current code does.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim myChartData As ChartData
    Dim gWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim gWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart
    Set myChartData = myChart.ChartData
    myChartData.Activate

    Set gWorkBook = myChart.ChartData.Workbook
    Set gWorkSheet = gWorkBook.Worksheets(1)
    gWorkSheet.Range("B2").Value = 1

    gWorkBook.Close
    Set gWorkSheet = Nothing
    Set gWorkBook = Nothing
    Set gChartData = Nothing
    Set myChart = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: *While the Activate line is necessary to get access to the underlying Workbook*... I've been dealing with this foolish, foolish requirement for the better part of 2 years now, I still can't believe they require this...

Comment: @davidzemens agreed. PowerPoint logic is at times ... An oxymoron.